# Term for wall corner facing out?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology

I thought about posting this in woodworking, but everything there seems to be related to actual problems in carpentry.

I'm trying to describe a kitten’s behaviour:  **Frisky's so desperate for an opponent to wrestle with, even the [wall corner] will do.**  I want to know if there's a technical term for this kind of corner.  I already tried searching here and also googling ***convex corner***, ***corner facing out***, and ***wall corner facing out***, all without finding the sought after term.

Here's a picture of the actual thing:

[image]

Comment: You mean like a quoin or coign? And do you mean looking at it from the inside or from the outside, so thrusting towards you or away from you?

Comment: Convex, so thrusting toward you (the other way would be concave, altho I'm not sure I'm using these terms correctly if referring to corners on walls).

Comment: I just looked up your terms, and yup, that's what I was looking for.  {thumbs up}

Comment: The everyday term for this is just "outside corner" as seen in [this ELL question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/90903/37569). This question isn't quite a duplicate of that one (you seem to be looking for the terminology used in that question, and that OP accepted an answer using the terminology you used, plus it's a different site), but I think @tchrist's answer here would be an excellent answer to that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a word *quoin* or *coign*, which were originally variants of *coin* but relate to corner. [Per the OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/156875?rskey=8OELwH&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid):

> 1. *Building*.
>
>    - a. Originally: an external angle of a wall; an outer corner of a building. Subsequently also: any of the stones or bricks serving to form this angle; a cornerstone. Cf. *coin* *n*. 1.
>
>      > Esp. used of cornerstones of a material or decoration differing from that of the rest of the wall.
>    - b. An internal angle or corner of a wall, esp. of a room. Also: a recess in a wall, as for a gate; = *hollow quoin* n. at *hollow* adj. and adv. Special uses 3b.

The *coign* version is less often seen these days. The OED says that when it means the same as *quoin*, then *quoin* is the ordinary modern spelling.

Various other specialized senses of *quoin* exist, but this is the oldest of them all.

Comment: Well, yes, but don't expect to be understood if you use this word in a general context. Perhaps builders or interior decorators will know it, but I didn't!

Comment: Any builder worth their salt will immediately think of heavy stonework exterior corners, often found on brick buildings. The edge stones on either side of the keystone of masonry arches are also called quoins. I agree with @1006a that the workingman's term is [outside corner](https://www.google.com/search?q=plinth+blocks+for+outside+corners&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS724US727&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwis8NrSg4zdAhWLjlkKHUVZCSAQ_AUICygC&biw=1093&bih=505)

Answer (score 0):

Angular - having angles or sharp corners https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/angular